# Universal selector usage and differences

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

In the [Twitter Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css), you see this:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:before, :after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

What is the difference between ***that***, and this:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

So more specifically, I am asking what the differnce is between the selectors:

```
:before, :after
```

and

```
*:before, *:after
```

Also - if they are both the same, why do they have them seperate and repeat it? It takes more CSS. It really isn't shorter if they are the same.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [commit where the declaration was changed](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/380019ccb28ef1205e0a114e386ab2cc4281efb4) splitting the declaration in two speeds up rendering. This makes sense because the universal selector is already slow so making the browser look for all elements AND all pseudo-elements at the same time slows down the browser even further.

I asked the developer who made the commit why he made the change and he said during testing splitting the two declaration noticeably improved rendering performance in Safari and Chrome. (See his comment on the [commit page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/380019ccb28ef1205e0a114e386ab2cc4281efb4)). However, I haven't been able to find any documentation from the W3C or the browser vendors indicating that one way of declaring things should be faster than another. It seems the difference in performance between browsers is based on how the rendering engine is written.

---

The difference between

```
:before, :after
```

and

```
*:before, *:after
```

is similar to the difference between

```
.class
```

and

```
*.class
```

in that there is virtually no difference. If anything qualifying a class with `*` slows down the rendering. I believe `*` is added for style and readability and has no real effect.

Check out [this article](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/05/03/css-tricks-how-to-speed-up-css-rendering/) about selectors and rendering speed.

Comment: Personally I'm surprised that splitting the rules has any effect on rendering - I don't see how that would make a browser behave any differently. The article you linked to doesn't explain either concept at all.

Comment: I don't see how qualifying a selector with `*` would slow down rendering either. Sure, a browser would at the very least have to notice the `*` and throw it away as redundant, but how slow could that be?

Comment: Performance is, by definition, an implementation detail. The spec describes features, but cannot describe the performance of a feature since it is not the job of a spec to define how a feature should be implemented. That said, I'm curious to find out how exactly Safari and Chrome are handling the selector to have such results.